# In TypeScript, how do I make a function's return type based on the return type of one of its arguments?

Tags: typescript

Is there some way I can have a function whose return type varies based on one of its arguments? For example:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  job: string;
}

interface Animal {
  name: string;
  deadly: boolean;
}

function getPerson(): Person {
  return {
    name: 'Bob',
    job: 'Manager',
  };
}

function getAnimal(): Animal {
  return {
    name: 'Spot',
    deadly: false,
  };
}

function create(generator: () => Person | Animal): ReturnType<typeof generator>[] {
  return []
}

const people = create(getPerson);
```

This is kind of close, except the type of `people` is `(Person | Animal)[]`. I need it to be `Person[]` - in other words, it can look at the `getPerson` argument and know that this function will return a `Person`. I realize, of course, I could rewrite the function so I can do this:

```
const people = create<Person>(getPerson);
```

But I'd rather have it infer this from the arguments somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I just modified this part of the above code:

```
function create<M>(generator: () => M): M[] {
  return []
}

const people = create(getPerson);
const animals = create(getAnimal);
```

And that worked.

Comment: I was just about to add `function create<T>(generator: () => T): T[] {
  return []
}`, and you beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You've already figured it out, I just wanted to add that the concept is called "generics", if you want to look it up / learn more.

Comment: Yep, I know what they're called and how to use them (mostly.. sort of). I thought anything I passed as a generic had to be passed when calling the function, e.g. `create<Whatever>()`. I had no idea I could use them in this way, which is really cool!